# Group medians from a data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, median, summary

Computing medians seems to be [a bit of an achilles heel for R](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-September/058604.html) (ie. [no data.frame method](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060738.html)). What is the least amount of typing needed to get group medians from a data frame using dplyr?

```
my_data <- structure(list(group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", 
"Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", 
"Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", 
"Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", 
"Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", 
"Group 2", "Group 2"), value = c("5", "3", "6", "8", "10", "13", 
"1", "4", "18", "4", "7", "9", "14", "15", "17", "7", "3", "9", 
"10", "33", "15", "18", "6", "20", "30", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("group", 
"value"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

library(dplyr)  

# groups 1 & 2
my_data_groups_1_and_2 <- my_data[my_data$group %in% c("Group 1", "Group 2"), ]

# compute medians per group
medians <- my_data_groups_1_and_2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(the_medians = median(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What is the least effort workaround here?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing a trick here, but isn't this failing because `is.character(my_data_groups_1_and_2$value)` is `TRUE`? Adding in a mutate and converting value to double allows medians to be computed for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by ivyleavedtoadflax, the error is caused by supplying a non-numeric or non-logical argument to `median`, since your `value` column is of type `character` (you can easily tell that they are not `numeric` by seeing that the numbers are quoted). Here are two simple ways to solve it:

```
my_data %>% 
  filter(group %in% c("Group 1", "Group 2")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(the_medians = median(as.numeric(value), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or

```
my_data %>% 
  filter(group %in% c("Group 1", "Group 2")) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value))  %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(the_medians = median(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

To check the structure including `type` of columns in your data, you could conveniently use

```
str(my_data)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ group: chr  "Group 1" "Group 1" "Group 1" "Group 1" ...
# $ value: chr  "5" "3" "6" "8" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect, much simpler than I thought. I completely overlooked the numbers-as-character-type error message